# Record a call made from Plivo WebSDK using API or XML

Tags: javascript, xml, api, sdk, plivo

I want to be able to record the call that's being initialized through the PlivoWebSDK. How can I accomplish that without having to change my whole setup to API or XML. Both seems to be much more complicated to me.

```
function RecordTheCall(CallUUID)
        {
            console.log(callUuid);
            var auth_id = "MAM2M4ZGE3NJIWMGRIM2";
            var url = "https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/"+auth_id+"/Call/"+CallUUID+"/Record/";
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: { 'auth_id': auth_id, 'call_uuid': CallUUID },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (res) {
                    alert(res);
                },
                error: function(err) {
                    alert(err);
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Call recording cannot be accomplished from the Web SDK directly. You cannot use the Plivo API from your Web browser using Javascript because cross-domain ajax requests are not allowed in browsers for security reasons.

There are 2 ways to record a call initialized from the Plivo Web SDK.

- Method 1: Using the Plivo XML (The most straight-forward method)
  You can use the Record XML element for recording the call session. More information [here](https://www.plivo.com/docs/xml/record/).
- Method 2: Using Plivo API
  You can use the Record API for recording the call session. More information [here](https://www.plivo.com/docs/api/call/record/)

There are some documents available [here](https://www.plivo.com/docs/getting-started/web-sdk/quick-start/) that can help you get started on using Plivo's Web SDK.

Comment: i dont understand the xml where do i initiate it and how to, where do i make the request and how?

Comment: These docs should help you get started on using the Web SDK and configuring your application to return a valid XML - https://www.plivo.com/docs/getting-started/web-sdk/quick-start/